# How to make KeePass2 work correctly in the Unity launcher?

Tags: unity, launcher, mono, keepass

KeePass2 is a Mono app.
In the launcher it appears as "Untitled window" and has a grey icon with a question mark.
When I "Keep in Launcher" the icon doesn't launch the application

How to fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a bug already open for the problem you describe:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/768931

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should report this as bug for the keepass2 Ubuntu package

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/keepass2/+filebug

Comment: Yes I should. As a side note, I posted this question before the Ubuntu package was launched (or, at least, before I realized that it was)

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial fix, not a solution for all problems listed.

I was able to create a launcher for it.

1. Right click the desktop
2. Click add launcher
3. Give it a name "KeePass2"
4. Tell it to execute "keepass2"
5. Drag it to the launcher

But it still shows the "untitled window" in the launcher along the new icon.

Answer (score 0):

Another partial solution:

1. Install the new Ubuntu package

> sudo apt-add-repository ppa:jtaylor/keepass
>
> sudo apt-get update
>
> sudo apt-get install keepass2

1. Open the launcher and type `Keepass2`
2. Drag the icon to the launcher

But it still shows the "untitled window" in the launcher along the new icon.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on my end by calling the application without arguments. Using terminal navigate to  /usr/share/applications  by typing

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

next use your favorite text editor I like vim,

```
sudo vim keepass2.desktop
```

after this edit the line that says Exec=   it should invoke the program without arguments.

```
Exec=keepass2
```

save and quit which in vim happens by pressing Esc and typing wq for write quit!

Sorry for the more advanced I tried to do a step by step so everyone can follow the solution!